# Clearing Tensorflow GPU memory after model execution

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I've trained 3 models and am now running code that loads each of the 3 checkpoints in sequence and runs predictions using them. I'm using the GPU.

When the first model is loaded it pre-allocates the entire GPU memory (which I want for working through the first batch of data). But it doesn't unload memory when it's finished. When the second model is loaded, using both `tf.reset_default_graph()` and `with tf.Graph().as_default()` the GPU memory still is fully consumed from the first model, and the second model is then starved of memory.

Is there a way to resolve this, other than using Python subprocesses or multiprocessing to work around the problem (the only solution I've found on via google searches)?

Comment: What if you delete the session (del sess)? That should have the same effect on memory as restarting process

Comment: Shouldn't sess.close() (or using the Session as a context with `with`) also work?

Comment: I wish, I do use `with ... sess:` and have also tried `sess.close()`. GPU memory doesn't get cleared, and clearing the default graph and rebuilding it certainly doesn't *appear* to work. That is, even if I put 10 sec pause in between models I don't see memory on the GPU clear with `nvidia-smi`. That doesn't necessarily mean that tensorflow isn't handling things properly behind the scenes and just keeping its allocation of memory constant. But I'm having troubles validating that line of reasoning.

Comment: `nvidia-smi` doesn't correctly report amount of memory available to TensorFlow. When TensorFlow computation releases memory, it will still show up as reserved to outside tools, but this memory is available to other computations in tensorflow

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov I've done more testing and confirmed that tensorflow is performing as expected on the 2nd and 3rd models after simply resetting the default graph. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it as correct. It seems that this question is irrelevant, though probably commonly asked so worth keeping open.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

A git issue from June 2016 (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1727) indicates that there is the following problem:

> currently the Allocator in the GPUDevice belongs to the ProcessState,
>   which is essentially a global singleton. The first session using GPU
>   initializes it, and frees itself when the process shuts down.

Thus the only workaround would be to use processes and shut them down after the computation.

**Example Code:**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np

def run_tensorflow():

    n_input = 10000
    n_classes = 1000

    # Create model
    def multilayer_perceptron(x, weight):
        # Hidden layer with RELU activation
        layer_1 = tf.matmul(x, weight)
        return layer_1

    # Store layers weight & bias
    weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_classes]))


    x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_input])
    y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_classes])
    pred = multilayer_perceptron(x, weights)

    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred, labels=y))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(cost)

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)

        for i in range(100):
            batch_x = np.random.rand(10, 10000)
            batch_y = np.random.rand(10, 1000)
            sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})

    print "finished doing stuff with tensorflow!"


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # option 1: execute code with extra process
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=run_tensorflow)
    p.start()
    p.join()

    # wait until user presses enter key
    raw_input()

    # option 2: just execute the function
    run_tensorflow()

    # wait until user presses enter key
    raw_input()
```

So if you would call the function `run_tensorflow()` within a process you created and shut the process down (option 1), the memory is freed. If you just run `run_tensorflow()` (option 2) the memory is not freed after the function call.

Comment: I wrote a [small reusable wrapper](https://gist.github.com/MInner/9716950ac85b49821b56298117756451) that uses same trick as in this answer. However, performance degradation is severe, which is okay for small computations (i.e. inference on a small dataset), but not practical in any other scenario. I believe this must be due to inter-process communication and passing large numpy objects back and forth.

Comment: Can I use this to free GPU memory after loading a Keras model?

Comment: Related and important, multiprocessing.Process uses `spawn` as default on Windows, but, `fork` on *nix systems. If you find yourself in a situation where the model running in a separate Process is unable to use GPU i.e. `tf.test.is_gpu_available` is `False` while checking cross platform compatibility, you can force select the state using `multiprocessing.get_context('spawn')`. `spawn` is available for Windows, Linux and MacOS. More on context [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods)

Comment: This is a great answer.

Comment: So how to make multiprocessing works for jupyter notebook?

Comment: I can't get this to work, nor the small reusable wrapper listed by Ben Usman. The problem is that the parallel_wrapper is not picklable if using 'spawn' and the process hangs if using 'fork'. It's hard to believe that after nearly 4 years this is still such an issue with TF. does anybody know of a good resolution?

Answer (score 40):

You can use numba library to release all the gpu memory

```sh
pip install numba
```

```py
from numba import cuda 
device = cuda.get_current_device()
device.reset()
```

This will release all the memory

Comment: This leaves the GPU in a bad state.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what you mean by "leaves the GPU in a bad state"? That doesn't tell us the ramifications of using this approach.

Comment: I guess what he means is that this results in an " .\tensorflow/core/kernels/random_op_gpu.h:232] Non-OK-status: GpuLaunchKernel(FillPhiloxRandomKernelLaunch<Distribution>, num_blocks, block_size, 0, d.stream(), gen, data, size, dist) status: Internal: invalid resource handle" error. At least, that's the case for me.

Comment: perhaps by bad state, he means that this kills the kernel. this cannot be done in the midst of long processes

Comment: yes. This clears gpu and Kills the kernel also.

Comment: No this DOES NOT kill the Jupyter kernel.  It does clear everything in the GPU.

Answer (score 9):

I use [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.13/CUDADevice.html) to release GPU. With TensorFlow, I cannot find an effective method.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from numba import cuda

a = tf.constant([1.0,2.0,3.0],shape=[3],name='a')
b = tf.constant([1.0,2.0,3.0],shape=[3],name='b')
with tf.device('/gpu:1'):
    c = a+b

TF_CONFIG = tf.ConfigProto(
gpu_options=tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.1),
  allow_soft_placement=True)

sess = tf.Session(config=TF_CONFIG)
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
i=1
while(i<1000):
        i=i+1
        print(sess.run(c))

sess.close() # if don't use numba,the gpu can't be released
cuda.select_device(1)
cuda.close()
with tf.device('/gpu:1'):
    c = a+b

TF_CONFIG = tf.ConfigProto(
gpu_options=tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.5),
  allow_soft_placement=True)

sess = tf.Session(config=TF_CONFIG)

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
while(1):
        print(sess.run(c))
```

Comment: Running this code gives me an `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Failed to create session.` preceded by `Failed precondition: Failed to memcopy into scratch buffer for device 0`, when I try to run the `tf.Session()` after the `cuda.close(1)`

Comment: This leaves tensorflow in  a bad state

Comment: I was trying to find something for releasing GPU memory from a Kaggle notebook as I need to run a XGBoost on GPU after leveraging tensorflow-gpu based inference for feature engineering and this worked like a charm. Numba comes preinstalled and I just had to `del model_object` `gc.collect()` `from numba import cuda` `cuda.select_device(0)`
`cuda.close()`

Answer (score 7):

I was able to solve an OOM error just now with the garbage collector.

```py
import gc
gc.collect()

model.evaluate(x1, y1)
gc.collect()

model.evaluate(x2, y2)
gc.collect()
```

etc.

Based on what [Yaroslav Bulatov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39781178/12506728) said in their answer (that tf deallocates GPU memory when the object is destroyed), I surmised that it could just be that the garbage collector hadn't run yet. Forcing it to collect freed me up, so that might be a good way to go.

Answer (score 5):

Now there seem to be two ways to resolve the iterative training model or if you use future multipleprocess pool to serve the model training, where the process in the pool will not be killed if the future finished. You can apply two methods in the training process to release GPU memory meanwhile you wish to preserve the main process.

1. call a subprocess to run the model training. when one phase training completed, the subprocess will exit and free memory. It's easy to get the return value.
2. call the multiprocessing.Process(p) to run the model training(p.start), and p.join will indicate the process exit and free memory.

Here is a helper function using multiprocess.Process which can open a new process to run your python written function and reture value instead of using Subprocess,

```
# open a new process to run function
def process_run(func, *args):
    def wrapper_func(queue, *args):
        try:
            logger.info('run with process id: {}'.format(os.getpid()))
            result = func(*args)
            error = None
        except Exception:
            result = None
            ex_type, ex_value, tb = sys.exc_info()
            error = ex_type, ex_value,''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))
        queue.put((result, error))

    def process(*args):
        queue = Queue()
        p = Process(target = wrapper_func, args = [queue] + list(args))
        p.start()
        result, error = queue.get()
        p.join()
        return result, error  

    result, error = process(*args)
    return result, error
```

Comment: I'm not sure I get the difference between the two methods you are talking about. They both look like just "use multiprocessing" to me. And there's already a nice and more detailed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44842044/1032586) about it.

Comment: In my sense, 'multiprocessing' and 'subprocess', they both spawn the new process to handle the GPU run and free but operate in different  ways

Comment: Should be noted that is multiprocessing.Queue and not queue.Queue

Answer (score 4):

I am figuring out which option is better in the Jupyter Notebook. Jupyter Notebook occupies the GPU memory permanently even a deep learning application is completed. It usually incurs the GPU Fan ERROR that is a big headache. In this condition, I have to reset nvidia_uvm and reboot the linux system regularly. I conclude the following two options can remove the headache of GPU Fan Error but want to know which is better.

**Environment:**

- CUDA 11.0
- cuDNN 8.0.1
- TensorFlow 2.2
- Keras 2.4.3
- Jupyter Notebook 6.0.3
- Miniconda 4.8.3
- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

**First Option**

Put the following code at the end of the cell. The kernel immediately ended upon the application runtime is completed. But it is not much elegant. Juputer will pop up a message for the died ended kernel.

```
import os
 
pid = os.getpid()
!kill -9 $pid
```

**Section Option**

The following code can also end the kernel with Jupyter Notebook. I do not know whether numba is secure. Nvidia prefers the "0" GPU that is the most used GPU by personal developer (not server guys). However, both Neil G and mradul dubey have had the response: This leaves the GPU in a bad state.

```
from numba import cuda

cuda.select_device(0)
cuda.close()
```

It seems that the second option is more elegant. Can some one confirm which is the best choice?

Notes:

It is not such the problem to automatically release the GPU memory in the environment of  Anaconda by direct executing "$ python abc.py". However, I sometimes need to use Jyputer Notebook to handle .ipynb application.

Comment: My test shows that numba is a better choice. However, users need to use pip install numba rather than conda install -c numba mumba or sudo apt-get install python-3 numba.  conda install... has an internal conflict and sudo apt-get install..could not be used.

Comment: This results in `Could not synchronize CUDA stream: CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE: invalid resource handle` error if run any code after performing the `cuda.close()`, is there any way to clear the CUDA memory without getting this error

Comment: I used the First Option a few times, and it worked well for me. Thanks. I tested on Tensorflow 2.4.

Answer (score 2):

GPU memory allocated by tensors is released (back into TensorFlow memory pool) as soon as the tensor is not needed anymore (before the .run call terminates). GPU memory allocated for variables is released when variable containers are destroyed. In case of DirectSession (ie, sess=tf.Session("")) it is when session is closed or explicitly reset (added in  [62c159ff](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/62c159ff))

Comment: As for now, tensorflow still doesn't release GPU memory with sess.Close() or after with tf.Session() as sess: , could you please update your answer considering comments above?

Comment: @yaroslav-bulatov you mentioned on your comments that `nvidia-smi` doesn't show the correct memory on a gpu.

I tried `tf.reset_default_graph()` and then rebuild the previous graph but I have an OOM error which suggests that `nvidia-smi` is displaying correctly the memory. Any thoughts?

Comment: @DiegoAgher what I meant that nvidia-smi may show 0 available memory, yet there's still plenty of memory available for TensorFlow to use. The reason is that TensorFlow takes over the memory management

Comment: @yaroslavBulatov so how would you go about freeing up space in the gpu if the tensorflow pool is still there and when building again the graph, I get the OOM error ?

Comment: It's freed up automatically. OOM error in tensorflow is typically caused by having models that are too large

Comment: I also have the OOM error which seems to be due to variables not being released.  For example the model will run and train several times, but after reassigning the variable (not changing the total size), it may give an OOM error.  Closing Spyder and reopening has been my only recourse..

Answer (score 1):

I have trained my models in a for loop for different parameters when I got this error after 120 models trained. Afterwards I could not even train a simple model if I did not kill the kernel.
I was able to solve my issue by adding the following line before building the model:

`tf.keras.backend.clear_session()`

(see https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/clear_session)

Answer (score 0):

To free my resources, I use:

```
import os, signal

os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGKILL)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, thant Oliver Wilken's user (Jun 30, 2017 at 8:30) is the best solution.
But in tensorflow 2 there is eager execution instead of sessions.
So you just need to import all the tensorflow and keras stuff inside the run_tensorflow(...) function.