# Stop Tensoflow from running on the GPU after a computation

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am running a REST Server in Python, with an access point to retrieve an image and use a tensorflow model to predict what is on that image. After starting the server, I am sending images to the REST endpoint. The model loaded is an Inception model that I trained myself. It is loaded from a tensorflow checkpoint file to restore the weights. Here is the function that builds the graph and executes the classification:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf

from cnn_server.server import file_service as dirs
from slim.datasets import dataset_utils
from slim.nets import nets_factory as network_factory
from slim.preprocessing import preprocessing_factory as preprocessing_factory  

def inference_on_image(bot_id, image_file, network_name='inception_v4', return_labels=1):

        model_path = dirs.get_model_data_dir(bot_id)

        # Get number of classes to predict
        protobuf_dir = dirs.get_protobuf_dir(bot_id)
        number_of_classes = dataset_utils.get_number_of_classes_by_labels(protobuf_dir)

        # Get the preprocessing and network construction functions
        preprocessing_fn = preprocessing_factory.get_preprocessing(network_name, is_training=False)
        network_fn = network_factory.get_network_fn(network_name, number_of_classes)

        # Process the temporary image file into a Tensor of shape [widht, height, channels]
        image_tensor = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_file, 'rb').read()
        image_tensor = tf.image.decode_image(image_tensor, channels=0)

        # Perform preprocessing and reshape into [network.default_width, network.default_height, channels]
        network_default_size = network_fn.default_image_size
        image_tensor = preprocessing_fn(image_tensor, network_default_size, network_default_size)

        # Create an input batch of size one from the preprocessed image
        input_batch = tf.reshape(image_tensor, [1, 299, 299, 3])

        # Create the network up to the Predictions Endpoint
        logits, endpoints = network_fn(input_batch)

        restorer = tf.train.Saver()

        with tf.Session() as sess:
            tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

            # Restore the variables of the network from the last checkpoint and run the graph
            restorer.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_path))
            sess.run(endpoints)

            # Get the numpy array of predictions out of the
            predictions = endpoints['Predictions'].eval()[0]
            sess.close()

        return map_predictions_to_labels(protobuf_dir, predictions, return_labels)
```

To build the graph of the Inception V4 model I used `tf.model.slim`, a collection of tensorflow implementations of state-of-the-art CCNs. The inception model is built here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/nets/inception_v4.py and provided via a factory method: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/nets/nets_factory.py

For the first image everythig works as expected:

```
2017-07-17 18:00:43.831365: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:908] DMA: 0 
2017-07-17 18:00:43.831371: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:918] 0:   Y 
2017-07-17 18:00:43.831384: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:977] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
192.168.0.192 - - [17/Jul/2017 18:00:46] "POST /classify/4 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

The second image creates the following Error:

```
ValueError: Variable InceptionV4/Conv2d_1a_3x3/weights already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope? Originally defined at:
```

My understanding of this is that the graph is created initially and then keeps on existing somewhere. Sending a second image results in calling the function again, the attempt to recreate the existing graph and then in the error. Now I have tried some things:

**Stopping Tensorflow overall:**
I tried to stop tensorflow overall and recreate the device each time on the GPU. That would be the best solution, since this way the GPU is not occupied by Tensorflow when the server is running. I tried to do that with `sess.close()`, which did not work. `nvidia-smi` still shows the process on the GPU after processing the first image. Then I tried to access the devices somehow, but all I could get is the list of available devices via `device_lib.list_local_devices()`. However, this did not result in any option to manipulate the tensorflow processes on the GPU. Stopping the server, i.e. the initial python script that started the tensorflow session also kills off tensorflow on the GPU. Restarting the server after each classification is not an elegant solution.

**Reset or Delete the Graph**
I tried to reset the Graph in several ways. One way is to retrieve the Graph from the tensor I am running, iterate over all collections and clearing them:

```
graph = endpoints['Predictions'].graph
for key in graph.get_all_collection_keys():
    graph.clear_collection(key)
```

Debugging shows that the graph collections are empty afterwards, however the error remains the same. The other way is to set the graph from the endpoint as default graph as `with graph.as_default:`, since the graph has been created before I didn't have much hope that this would delete the graph after the computation. It didn't.

**Set the variable scope to `reuse=true`**
The variable scope has an option reuse, which you can set in the `inception_v4.py`.

```
def inception_v4(inputs, num_classes=1001, is_training=True,
                 dropout_keep_prob=0.8,
                 reuse=None,
                 scope='InceptionV4',
                 create_aux_logits=True):
```

Setting it to true, results in an error creating the graph initially, saying that the Variables do not exist.

**Loading the model once, then resuing it**
Another way I thought of is to create the model once and then just reuse it, i.e. avoid calling the network factory a second time. Now this is problematic, since the server holds several models, which work on a different number of classes each. This means, I would have to create the graph for each of these models, keep them all alive and maintain them somehow. While this is possible, it causes a lot of overhead and is somewhat redundant since the model is always the same, just the weights and the final layer differ. The weights are stored in checkpoint files already and the implementations in `tf.model.slim` allows to easily create a graph with a different number of classes for the output.

I am out of ideas here. The most desirable solution would of course be to completely terminate tensorflow on the GPU and recreate the device from scratch each time the function is called.

Hope anybody can help here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Let's go over your problems one by one.

First, the error about the variable already existing comes from you reusing an existing graph and rerunning the model creation code on every request. Either create a graph per request by adding a `with tf.Graph().as_default():` context manager inside your `inference_on_image` function, or (strongly recommended) reuse the graph, by separating the part of that function which does `session.run` on the network from model building and weight loading.

For the second issue, there is no way to have tensorflow reset its GPU state without killing off the entire process.

For the third issue, clearing the graph collections won't do much. You can use a new graph per request but this will still share the state of the variables by default, as they will reside on the GPU. You can use session.reset to clear that state, but this won't get you your ram back.

To reuse the model with the different number of classes while sharing weights it sounds like you need to have a function which constructs all of them. I think the best way to do that is to change the implementation of the slim method to return up to the last layer, and then have your own code add the fully connected layers with the right numbers of classes on top of that.

Of course, you'd probably still want different parameter values for the rest of the network, unless you train all your models together.

Comment: Tanks for the reply. Reusing the graph means to keep several quite large inception v4 models in memory. That doesn't seem like a good idea to me, especially since tf doenst seem to offer any way to delete graphs. Also the problem remains, that tensorflow still occupies the GPU. With standard configuration no other process can do anything on the GPU in the meantime, which is not desirable as well. I chose to start the function in a dedicated thread, which terminates after inference (see my answer below). That works best for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44842044/7208993

The idea is to execute the function in a process, which terminates after execution. The results can be ontained by sharing a variable with the `Manager()` object. While this is probably not the most elegant solution, tensorflow doesn't seem to offer a better way right now. Since the GPU is not occupied by Tensorflow the whole time the server runs, this is more than sufficient. The code now looks like this:

```
    def inference_on_image(bot_id, image_file, network_name='inception_v4', return_labels=1):
        manager = Manager()
        prediction_dict = manager.dict()
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=infere, args=(bot_id, image_file, network_name, return_labels, prediction_dict))
        process.start()
        process.join()
        return prediction_dict['predictions']


    def infere(bot_id, image_file, network_name='inception_v4', return_labels=1, prediction_dict=[]):
        # Get the model path
        model_path = dirs.get_model_data_dir(bot_id)

        # Get number of classes to predict
        protobuf_dir = dirs.get_protobuf_dir(bot_id)
        number_of_classes = dataset_utils.get_number_of_classes_by_labels(protobuf_dir)

        # Get the preprocessing and network construction functions
        preprocessing_fn = preprocessing_factory.get_preprocessing(network_name, is_training=False)
        network_fn = network_factory.get_network_fn(network_name, number_of_classes)

        # Process the temporary image file into a Tensor of shape [widht, height, channels]
        image_tensor = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_file, 'rb').read()
        image_tensor = tf.image.decode_image(image_tensor, channels=0)

        # Perform preprocessing and reshape into [network.default_width, network.default_height, channels]
        network_default_size = network_fn.default_image_size
        image_tensor = preprocessing_fn(image_tensor, network_default_size, network_default_size)

        # Create an input batch of size one from the preprocessed image
        input_batch = tf.reshape(image_tensor, [1, 299, 299, 3])

        # Create the network up to the Predictions Endpoint
        logits, endpoints = network_fn(input_batch)

        restorer = tf.train.Saver()

        with tf.Session() as sess:
            tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

            # Restore the variables of the network from the last checkpoint and run the graph
            restorer.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_path))
            sess.run(endpoints)

            # Get the numpy array of predictions out of the
            predictions = endpoints['Predictions'].eval()[0]
            sess.close()
            graph = endpoints['Predictions'].graph

            prediction_dict['predictions'] = map_predictions_to_labels(protobuf_dir, predictions, return_labels)
```