# K.ctc_decode() memory not released

Tags: keras

when using K.ctc_decode() like the code below in a large loop, the memory cost more and more, and time cost longer and longer.

```
 out = K.get_value(K.ctc_decode(y_pred, input_length=np.ones(y_pred.shape[0])*y_pred.shape[1], )[0][0])[:, :]
```

How can I solve it ?

Comment: Do you use `GPU`?

Comment: yes, I use GPU.

Comment: Check second answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758094/clearing-tensorflow-gpu-memory-after-model-execution) question.