# How to create and delete class instance in python for loop

Tags: python, class, tensorflow, memory-leaks

I am using a class to create a tensorflow model. Within a for loop, I am creating an instance which I must delete at the end of each iteration in order to free up memory. Deletion does not work and I am running out of memory. Here is a minimal example of what I tried:

```
import numpy as np

class tfModel(self, x):
   def __init__(self, x):
      ....

   def predict(self, x):
      ...
      return x_new


if __name__=="__main__":

   x = np.ones(100)
   for i in range(0, 3):
      model = tfModel(x)
      x = model.predict(x)
      del model
```

I've read in related questions that "del" only deletes a reference, not the class instance itself. But how can I ensure that all references are deleted and the instance can be garbage collected?

Comment: Python does not provide any way to directly manage memory, it is a garbage collected language. `del` deletes *names* not objects. In this case, since you are re-assigning `model` on each iteration of the loop, `del model` is totally pointless

Comment: I tried to use garbage collector (import gc)  also and manually typed 'gc.collect' after 'del model', but still no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a specific tensorflow problem. Using the module multiprocessing, one can generate processes within a for loop. The processes are closed when finished and the memory is freed.

I found this solution here:
[Clearing Tensorflow GPU memory after model execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758094/clearing-tensorflow-gpu-memory-after-model-execution)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about two things:

1. the model itself. I assume your model can fit in your memory. Otherwise you could not run any prediction.
2. the data. If data is the problem, you should make a data [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) with python so that not all the data exist in the memory at the same time. You should generate each example (`x`) or each batch of examples and feed them into the model to get prediction. The result could be serialized to disk when necessary if your memory cannot hold all results.

More concretely, something like this:

```
class tfModel(self):
   def __init__(self):
      ....

   def predict(self, x):
      ...
      return x_new

def my_x_generator():
  for x in range(100):
    yield x


THRESHOLD = 16

if __name__=="__main__":

   model = tfModel()
   my_result_buffer = []
   for x in my_x_generator():
      x_pred = model.predict(x)
      my_result_buffer.append(x_pred)
      if len(my_result_buffer) > THRESHOLD:
        ## serialize my_result_buffer to disk
        my_result_buffer = []
```

Also note that in my sample code above:

1. The constructor of `tfModel` should not depend on `x`. (`x` is removed from `__init__`). Of course, you could use model parameters to initialize your model.
2. You should instantiate your model outside of the data loop. E.g., the model only needs to be instantiated once; the same model would be used to do predictions for all examples.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I really need to create model instances within the for loop, because the prediction is used to build up the new model.

Comment: Therefore, I have to create and delete the model within a for loop. For the first iterations, the model perfectly fits in my memory. However, the memory occupied by my model is increasing with each iteration. I thought that "model" would not exist at the beginning of an iteration step, but it does...