# Colab RAM is Almost Full After Training Although I Delete The Variables

Tags: python, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, ram

recently I am using Google Colab GPU for training a model. after the training, I delete the large variables that I have used for the training, but I notice that the ram is still full. I wonder what is really happening and what is exactly in the ram and how can I free up the ram without restarting?

Comment: please specify which ram you mean?! (GPU memory or CPU memory), which framework you are using? (tf/pytorch/...) how you free up the memory?!

Comment: as I saw both GPU and CPU were almost full comparing before and after training and I used Tensorflow Keras framework.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think variable itself will use much memory.

If you have the choice, you can try colab pro. Then you will have the option to access the high-memory VMs (see [here](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/pro.ipynb)). The price is $9.99/month.

One (maybe not very good) is to use a smaller dataset. Note that you have much more disk space than RAM. What I did was split the original dataset into several smaller sets, then trained the neural network with these dataset.

Another way is to check your code, find if there are some variables storing large array but you just use them once. Then you can set these variables to be zero or empty lists. It's like:

```
a = np.load("a_very_large_array.npy")
foo(a) # use array a only here
a = []
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that someone can post a better answer. Sharing so my account gets a notification if someone else has a fix

This is how I handle the issue:

1. Use `#@param` annotations to create input widgets which cache the high memory operation
2. The first time it runs, check the input widget to regenerate the data
3. After generating the data, uncheck the input widget to load the results from GDrive

[image]

Colab Python:

```
import pickle
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount(r'/content/gdrive/')
CACHE_DIR = "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/CACHE_DIR/"

regenerate_HIGH_MEM_models = True #@param{type:"boolean"}
HIGH_MEM_models_file = "HIGH_MEM_models_2022.pkl"  #@param {type:"string"}

if regenerate_HIGH_MEM_models:
  HIGH_MEM_models = generate_models_HIGH_MEM()
  with open(f"{CACHE_DIR}{ranked_universe_models_file}", "wb") as file: 
      pickle.dump(HIGH_MEM_models, file)
else:
  #@markdown (will load file from Gdrive if not regenerating)
  with open(f"{CACHE_DIR}{HIGH_MEM_models_file}", "rb") as file: 
      HIGH_MEM_models = pickle.load(file)
```

Answer (score -4):

**THIS SOLUTION DOES NOT WORK NOW!**

---

As for the GPU memory refer to [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758094/clearing-tensorflow-gpu-memory-after-model-execution)  (the subprocess solution and numba GPU memeory reset worked for me before):

CPU memory is usually used for the GPU-CPU data transfer, so nothing to do here, but you can have more memory with simple trick as:

```
a=[]
while True:
    a.append('qwertyqwerty')
```

the colab runtime will stop and give you an option to increase memory.

happy deep learning!