# GPU memory leakage when creating objects from sentence-transformers

Tags: r, python-3.x, pytorch, transformer-model, reticulate

## **Description**

I am creating a function in R that embeds sentences using the `sentence_transformers` library from Python.

For some unknown reason, creating the object multiple times under the same variable name ends up in insufficient memory space to allocate the transformer. To reproduce:

```
sentence_transformers <- reticulate::import("sentence_transformers")
for (i in 1:10) {
  print(i)
  bert_encoder <- sentence_transformers$SentenceTransformer("bert-large-nli-stsb-mean-tokens")
}
```

However, doing the same operation directly on Python does not produce an error

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
    bert_encoder = SentenceTransformer("bert-large-nli-stsb-mean-tokens")
}
```

This happens with any model that is allocated in GPU. On my NVIDIA GTX 1060 it reaches the 4th cycle, but on smaller GPUs it crashes earlier. One temporal solution is to create the model outside only once, and then pass the model as a parameter to the function as many times as wanted, but I would rather avoid that because it adds an extra step and in any case calling multiple models might just make it crash as well.

## **Expected behaviour**

The for loop finishes without an error

## **Observed behaviour**

*Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) :
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 20.00 MiB (GPU 0; 6.00 GiB total capacity; 2.95 GiB already allocated; 16.11 MiB free; 238.68 MiB cached)*

## **Unsuccesful attemps at solving it**

1. The solutions proposed [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36465)
2. Using numba as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60354785/5559413)
3. Declaring the variable explicitely on Python via `reticulate::py_run_string()` and then doing `del bert_encoder` and calling the garbage collector

## **Details**

Windows 10 Home

Python 3.7.4

R 4.0.1

Reticulate 1.16

Torch 1.3.1

Tensorflow 2.2.0

Transformers 2.11.0

sentence_transformers 0.2.6

Comment: hi. I had the same issue with `tf$...` syntax, for some reason GPU memory was not released after loops. What worked for me, i m not sure why, was to reimplement whole algorithm with keras functions, instead of using `tf$add` I have used `layer_add` and then memory were released as it should.

Comment: @JacobJacox could you please elaborate on how I would do what you suggested? I am not implementing a network from scratch, but rather loading a pretrained model, so I can not see how you suggestion might suit me

Comment: I know it is not pleasant but I did not find other alternative for this memory loop problem. If you look how custom model are implemented, you could do it probably in half a day, and if you folllow their source code from Github, you can take their weights to speed up training. If everything else fails, this is almost certain it will work.

Comment: @JacobJacox Have a look at my proposed solution. It solved the issue for me.

Comment: Hi, i see, unfortunately i am not familiar with pytorch, only tensorflow, but kudos if it works :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I am posting my solution for anyone else having this issue.

After each call to the model as

```r
sentence_transformers <- import("sentence_transformers")
encoder <- sentence_transformers$SentenceTransformer("bert-large-nli-stsb-mean-tokens")
```

I release GPU memory using

```r
  # Has this been done on a GPU?
  py <- reticulate::py_run_string("import torch
is_cuda_available = torch.cuda.is_available()")

  # Release GPU
  if (isTRUE(reticulate::py$is_cuda_available)) {

    tryCatch(reticulate::py_run_string("del encoder"),
             warning = function(e) {},
             error = function(e) {})

    tryCatch(rm(encoder),
             warning = function(e) {},
             error = function(e) {})

    gc(full = TRUE, verbose = FALSE)

    py <- reticulate::py_run_string("import torch
torch.cuda.empty_cache()")

  }
```

and it works perfectly.