# Is there a way to clear GPU memory after training the TF2 model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I’m training multiple models sequentially, which will be memory-consuming if I keep all models without any cleanup. However, I am not aware of any way to the graph and free the GPU memory in Tensorflow 2.x. Is there a way to do so?
Below is my code.

```
import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
import pandas as pd
import traceback
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from pickle import load, dump
import tensorflow as tf
from imblearn.under_sampling import RandomUnderSampler
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.layers import Conv1D, BatchNormalization, GlobalAveragePooling1D, Permute, Dropout
from keras.layers import Input, Bidirectional, CuDNNLSTM, concatenate, Activation
from keras.models import Model, load_model
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

for idx in range(10):
    ep = 20
    #load X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test

    for size in units:
        #create model
        model = Model(ip, out)
        model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                 loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
                 metrics=[
                 # tf.keras.metrics.Precision(),
                 # tf.keras.metrics.Recall()
                 ])
        model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=ep, batch_size=256, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

Comment: Have you considered using a function? The local scope would be cleared when the function exits.

Comment: Why are you importing all these libraries you never use in the first place? And why are the imports in the loop?

Comment: Doing even a single import inside a function is *weird*. Doing a dizzying number of them inside a loop is **ridiculous**. If you have different import requirements, split your code up into different files so they each get their own (relatively) clean namespace to start with.

Comment: If you are running out of memory, it's highly unlikely any individual module uses more than a very small fraction of the memory used by any one data set. Don't put the import statements in the loop, but not because it's causing a memory issue, but because there is no reason to do so. (The first time you import a module, a new `module` instance is created for it; each import after that simply and unnecessarily  reassigns the `module` object to a name.)

Comment: Got how to reset GPU after first model from this post:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758094/clearing-tensorflow-gpu-memory-after-model-execution . This way need not to clear all the variables and imports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using separate processes for separate models sequentially solves the issue.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Conv1D, BatchNormalization, GlobalAveragePooling1D, Permute
from keras.layers import Input, CuDNNLSTM, concatenate, Activation
from keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from multiprocessing import Process

def train(size):
    #load dataset and create model
    model = Model(ip, out)
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
             loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
             metrics=[
             # tf.keras.metrics.Precision(),
             # tf.keras.metrics.Recall()
             ])
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=ep, batch_size=256, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_models = 3
    for size in num_models:
        p = Process(target=train, args=(size))
        p.start()
        p.join()
```